# how can I simulate hardware key Back on windows phone 7 real device?

Tags: windows-phone-7, automation

I want to simulate hardware key Back from PC. It's for automation test. I use windows phone   test framework by expensify, but it do not support real device.

Comment: No code, no explanation, no example, no... Poor question!

Comment: Without any more details on just about anything, I can only suggest http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/ITAPPMONROBOT.aspx ;-)

Comment: @Abbas, Joachim - actually this question does make sense if you know a bit about the test framework. Apart from a link (https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/) - I can't think of much else that wade Lee could have supplied in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done on the real device unless you use robots (I am talking with LessPainful and this may happen one day!)

If this is required for your real device automation tests now, then the only things I can suggest are:

- that you hook a new custom command into the automation stack and then respond to that command by calling Back on the RootFrame's navigation stack.
- this might not be a perfect simulation of what would happen for a real back button press (e.g. if a modal dialog is up) - in which case you'll need to engineer code into your app to simulate the flow of the back press.
- if you ask around on XDA developers then someone might have a solution for you (there are ways to hack the OS on your test phont...)

Comment: @Stuart-thanks for you help,one more question,how to realize flick the pivot item on real device?On the Emulator,the expensify test framework realize it with simulating the windows mouse event.

Comment: answer.... same as for back button - robots or code workaround. any more new questions, use a new question.